# File Mime Type Checking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, mime-types

I am allowing uploading of files to my C# MVC website, I am restricting those types based on extension at the moment, but also feel I need a server side check to confirm they haven't just renamed it.

Is there a technique that I can use to check all the types I need or a library I can use that will help here?

I have seen people checking the first few bytes of the file, but I am scared I will miss something?

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

There are a lot of suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature). I will investigate some of these as a solution.

Comment: If all you got is a bunch of bytes, then I'm afraid it's going to be a bit difficult. If you're only dealing with images, you can always check for specific headers.

Comment: it will be image types as well as other mime types such as doc, xls, pdfs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up mixing some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435701/148998), because I am not using the HttpFileBase and only have the file stream, I had to read the first few bytes of the stream to determine the mime type.

Note: I don't use the registry technique because I don't know what will or wont be installed on the servers.

Answer (score 3):

If you are reading the file as an HttpPostedFile you can get the content type which is equal to the mime type.

So then you can do the following:

```
if (myFile.ContentType == "video/mpeg")
{
   // Do your thing
}
else{
   // error
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019874/is-httppostedfile-contenttype-a-flawless-way-to-validate-an-uploaded-file

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution: [Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature?lq=1)

It will do file content sniffing for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the MIME type in the following way:

```
var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

                mimeType = file.ContentType;
```

Once MIME type is obtained, it can be compared with string comparison (as shown by @ffffff01 )

Answer (score 0):

For more safety you can also check both mimeType with the *ContentType* property as ffffff01 said, and file extension with *Path.GetExtension* method.

Answer (score 0):

**Client side**

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileUploader" accept=".pdf,.docx"/>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="fileUploaderV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fileUploader"  ErrorMessage="Only .pdf, .docx formats are allowed"
                ValidationExpression="(.+\.([Pp][Dd][Ff])|.+\.([Dd][Oo][Cc][Xx]))" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**Server side**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 [DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
        static extern int FindMimeFromData      (IntPtr pBC,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzUrl,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1, SizeParamIndex = 3)] byte[] pBuffer,
    int cbSize,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzMimeProposed,
    int dwMimeFlags, out IntPtr ppwzMimeOut, int dwReserved);

    public static string getMimeFromFile(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        IntPtr mimeout;

        int MaxContent = (int)file.ContentLength;
        if (MaxContent > 4096) MaxContent = 4096;

        byte[] buf = new byte[MaxContent];
        file.InputStream.Read(buf, 0, MaxContent);
        int result = FindMimeFromData(IntPtr.Zero, file.FileName, buf, MaxContent, null, 0, out mimeout, 0);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeout);
            return "";
        }

        string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeout);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeout);

        return mime.ToLower();
    }
}
```